# How to sort values in multi nested dictionary and select first n values in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

### My dictionary is like this :

```
dict = { '2020-10-11' : { 
                           'group1':{ 
                                     1 : 2356,
                                     21 : 10001,
                                     34 :  234 
                                   },
                            'group2':{
                                     11 : 999,
                                     2  : 101,
                                     13 : 1234 
                                     } 
                         },
         '2020-10-12' : { 
                           'group1':{ 
                                     11 : 236,
                                     21 : 100,
                                     34 :  34 
                                   },
                            'group2':{
                                     1 : 99,
                                     3 : 121,
                                     2 : 12 
                                     } 
                         }


}
```

I want to sort it internally on the basis of the values present inside the group dictionaries and after sorting take the first two values only.(i.e out of three values the bigger two values)

#### I am expecting an output something like this :

```
dict = { '2020-10-11' : { 
                           'group1':{ 
                                     21 : 10001,
                                     1 : 2356
                                 
                                   },
                            'group2':{
                                     13 : 1234 
                                     11 : 999,
                                 
                                     } 
                         },
         '2020-10-12' : { 
                           'group1':{ 
                                     11 : 236,
                                     21 : 100,
                                    
                                   },
                            'group2':{
                                     3 : 121,
                                     1 : 99,
                                    
                                     } 
                         }


}
```

How should I proceed I have no clue.

### I am using python 3 for this.

Comment: you can use ordereddict from collections package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a way of doing it with `for` loops and `dict comprehension` with `sorted`:

```
for i in a:
  for x in a[i]:
    a[i][x] = {k: v for k, v in sorted(a[i][x].items(), key=lambda item: item[1],reverse=True)}
```

Output:

```
{'2020-10-11': {'group1': {21: 10001, 1: 2356, 34: 234},
                'group2': {13: 1234, 11: 999, 2: 101}},
 '2020-10-12': {'group1': {11: 236, 21: 100, 34: 34}, 
                'group2': {3: 121, 1: 99, 2: 12}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well seems like second part can be done by adding a single line of code snippet within the loop suggested by @celius:

```
a[i][x] = dict(itertools.islice(a[i][x].items(), 2))
```

i.e

```
import itertools
for i in a:
  for x in a[i]:
    a[i][x] = {k: v for k, v in sorted(a[i][x].items(), key=lambda item: item[1],reverse=True)}
    a[i][x] = dict(itertools.islice(a[i][x].items(), 2))
```